# Set pages pre-view in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

You can help me with this? (Make preview of next page on screen)
[image]

Comment: Does solution with the relatively new `CardView` is applicable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well... there is a way to do this. You need to keep 2 or 3 items in memory with:

```
vpPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); // or 2
```

Then, tune your viewpager like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Next, you need to tune these properties of the pager in the containing fragment or activity:

```
ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
vpPager.setClipToPadding(false);
vpPager.setPageMargin(12);
// Now setup the adapter as normal
```

Finally, adjust the width inside the adapter:

```
class MyPageAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth (int position) {
        return 0.93f;
    }   

    // ...
}
```

You can check a full example in this 2 links:

[Visible Adjacent](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter#viewpager-with-visible-adjacent-pages)

[ViewPager With Protruding Children](http://another950.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=4344684&item=48)